# Sitecore RTE class list not updating

Tags: .net, telerik, sitecore, rte

I am trying to add some custom classes into the RTE for Sitecore 6.5. I have added to the ToolsFile.xml & also the default.css file which I have confirmed is displaying the correct classes in my browser. However the drop down still does not display my classes. I am running on my local machine & have tried restarting IIS, emptying my browser caches & even restarting my machine so am starting to get a little stumped.

My xml schema is as below

```
<root>
    <modules></modules>
    <tools></tools>
    <tools></tools>
    <tools></tools> 
    <tools></tools> 
    <links></links>
    <snippets></snippets>
    <symbols></symbols> 
    <fontNames></fontNames> 
    <fontSizes></fontSizes>
    <colors></colors>   
    <paragraphs></paragraphs>
    **<classes>
        <class name="GreenText" value=".GreenText" />
            <class name="BlueText" value=".BlueText"/>
    </classes>**
    <dialogParameters></dialogParameters>
    <languages></languages>
    <contextMenus></contextMenus>
</root>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define the css file to be used on this config setting:

```
<!--CSS for the RichText-->
<setting name="WebStylesheet" value="/css/richtext.css" />
```

All classes in this css file will be available at the RTE

Once I also had to customize the list for hyperlinks classes, if you need something similar to that take a look at this blog post.
http://www.sitecoreinsight.com/how-to-define-the-list-of-css-class-in-the-apply-css-richtext-dropdown-list/

cheers.

Comment: I don't require to customise links at present, just list classes. In my web.config I have <setting name="WebStylesheet" value="~/default.css" /> I have also tried without the ~ My css file is in the root of the project & I can even see this stylesheet in the resources downloaded for the cms in my browser (so it looks as though it is getting through). Still nothing appearing on the actual drop down list though even after restarting/clearing everything I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Just clear your browser cache to get the rich text editor to update with your styles. You only get one css class per style, so no bootstrap styles like "btn btn-primary"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome browser, Try making css classes lower case, like greentext, bluetext, i faced this last week, and i discovered this by chance that css class needs to be lower case.
Also, try to change the name of css file in setting :
 
To something else, like ~/RTEStyle.css, just to make sure the browser refresh the cache for css file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advice guys, it turned out to just be a caching issue & started appearing a couple of days later. It seems like the most reliable way is to add the classes then change the xml file & finally kill everything you can think of (& any you can't) that may be doing some form of caching.